# Prevent angular directive from being called on load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say I have a file structured like this:

**index.html:**

```
<ng-header></ng-header>
<ng-body></ng-body>
<ng-footer></ng-footer>
<ng-modal></ng-modal>
```

All these directives are being loaded when I open up my index.html, however I dont want `<ng-modal>` to be loaded until I need it to be.

I tried to do smth like this:

```
<ng-modal ng-if="showModal"></ng-modal>
```

and then I would use ng-click somewhere in `<ng-body>` to open up this modal:

```
scope.openModal = function() {
  scope.showModal = true;
  console.log("Modal is initialized")
}
```

However this method is not really working for me because it initializes ng-modal only once and then when you open it again its already loaded and wont execute any http calls that I use in my modal.

---

ngModal.js:

```
.directive('nuMeetingCreate', function($scope) {
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     transclude: true,
     templateUrl: '../../../whatever.html',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       console.log("I am loaded"); // gets executed only once

       contacts.get({
         onSuccess: function success(response) {
           console.log("Contacts are loaded"); // this one gets called only once!       
         }, 
         onError: function error(response) {
           console.log(response)
         }
      });
     }
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you show your modal code? If you only want the directive code to execute when it is shown, you should try putting the functionality in the link function. You may consider breaking this logic into a service connected to a directive instead of a directive alone.

Comment: I suggest looking into [UI bootstrap's `$modal`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) service.

Comment: You obviously need more logic than just `show` anyway if modal is used multi-purpose. Show code for modal to see what it does.Also - side note, bad practice using `ng-` prefix for custom directives...implies they are part of angular core

Comment: updated the question. p.s. I am actually using foundation for apps.

Comment: http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Foundation then you should make use of their $modal service. There shouldn't be any need to predefine the modal div at the time the document is loaded. The modal content is rendered from a template when the service is called. You can use either a file based template or an inline template.